# Is there a limit to how many characters can be placed on a room space?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

Is there a limit to how many characters (specially monsters) can be placed on room space? I just played a session where the keeper placed 4 cultists, a shogoth, and two more monsters on the same *space* (space, not room) as the investigators, and it seemed to me that there is no logic to doing that in such a small space.

Answer (score 2):

I can understand that it looked odd but no, there is no limit on the number of monsters or investigators in a space.

Double checked the manual and it says nothing in either direction. So while the manual doesn't explicitly allow for unlimited number of monsters in a space it neither disallows it.